# Uncaught TypeError: is not a function when using window[functionName]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found [this page here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/calling-javascript-function-from-string/) about calling a function from a string. At the bottom there's an update that states it's better to use `window[functionName](params)`, and gives this example:

```
var strFun = "someFunction";
var strParam = "this is the parameter";

//Create the function
var fn = window[strFun];

//Call the function
fn(strParam);
```

So, I wrote this:

```
  var OnChange = function( e )
  {
    var oContainer = _.DOM.GetElementByAttribute( document, 'data-instance', _testInstance );

    var evt = ( e ) ? e : window.event;
    var objects = GetObjects( oContainer );
    var files = [];

    if( evt.target.files ) // html5 .. multiple?
    {
      for( var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++ )
        files.push( evt.target.files[i].name ); //  + " (" + Format.Size( evt.target.files[i].size ) + ")" );
    }
    else
    {
      files.push( evt.target.value );
    }

    var strFunc = "User.UploadPicture";
    var test = window[strFunc];
    test(e); // error
  };
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function

`User.Upload` is a function inside the js file. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you explicitly type `User.UploadPicture(e);` what response do you get?

Comment: are you sure you're not supposed to be using `window.User['UploadPicture']`

Comment: `User.UploadPicture` is not a function name. `User` is an object, and `UploadPicture` is a method of that object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: That calls my function, as desired. I'm new to js and a co-worker who was helping me pointed me in the direction of calling it by string. No idea why when this works as desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `User` is a globally scoped object containing a function `UploadPicture`, you would need to call it like this:

```
var test = window["User"]["UploadPicture"];
test(e);
```

`window["User.UploadPicture"]` refers to a property called, literally, "User.UploadPicture" on the `window` object, and is nothing to do with the `User` object.

In this instance however, the page you've linked to seems to be talking about calling a function that you'll determine the name of at runtime.  If, in your case, you're *always* going to call `User.UploadPicture`, there's nothing wrong with calling it directly:

```
User.UploadPicture(e);
```

You only need to use the other methods if *you don't know the name when you're writing the code*, and instead want to dynamically invoke different functions at runtime.

Comment: That makes much more sense. I hadn't had my coffee yet and was getting confused. This worked.